# Calling derived class method instead base class method c#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I have this array in program

```
ClassA[] array=new ClassA[20];

array[0]=new ClassB();
array[1]=new ClassA();
```

This is the class file

```
public class ClassA
{
    public void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
}
```

It writes 1, in both cases, but i want in first case to write 2, (to call method of ClassB).
How to do that?

Comment: Declare the base class method as `virtual`. Declare the derived class method as `override`. And please use conventional indentation in your code. The original formatting was difficult to read.

Comment: You need to read a c# tutorial... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You have to use override keyword in C# when you want to override method in child class.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public virtual void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
}
```

Regards.